# iOS: Изменение звука без отображения системного Volume Bar'a

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

Как сделать так, чтобы при программном изменении звука не выскакивал индикатор громкости устройства?

Есть приложение для iPad, проигрывающее видео. При выходе из видео программно изменяется звук (возвращается прежнее значение), при этом появляется индикатор громкости, хотелось бы, чтобы этого не было.

Для изменения громкости я использую этот код:

```
[[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:volumeApp];
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сделать следующее:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    MPVolumeView *volumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
    [self.view addSubview: volumeView];
    ...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Но это же `MPVolumeView`, а у меня все это делается через `MPMusicPlayerController`. Я бы с удовольствием использовал и `MPVolumeView`, но (наверное, я просто туплю) я не вижу в его описании в документации методов, которые изменяют значение громкости. Надо ли к нему добавлять какие-то еще объекты других классов, чтобы изменить громкость?

Comment: нет, пишут что этого будет достаточно, попробуйте))

Comment: @ИльяТерезников эпл по рукам не даст за такие подходы? :)

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko да пишут что вроде так без последствий, а так, конечно можно и недокументированными способами это сделать, но мы о них, не будем говорить)))

Comment: @mgv MPVolumeView не изменяет значение громкости, он является альтернативным способом оповещения пользователя об изменении громкости в приложении. Когда он присутствует система не должна показывать системный индикатор. А поскольку в примере выше размер MPVolumeView нулевой, то и его тоже не видно.